# How to test error get api request react query useInfiniteQuery with react testing library and jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-query

I have a function component that used react query useInfiniteQuery to get list data, now I try to test the useInfiniteQuery with error test case get API but still did not cover the onError object function. Does anyone know how to reach onError test with RTL and jest?

**useFetchListUsers.ts**

```
export const useFetchListUsers = (params) => {        
    const { users,
        error,
        isLoading,
        isFetching,
        fetchNextPage,
        hasNextPage } = useInfiniteQuery(['users', ...params], getAllUsers, {
            getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => {                            
                return ...lastPage;
            },
            onError: (error: AxiosError) => {
                return "Error get data Users from API"
            },
        });
    
    return { users, error, isLoading, isFetching, fetchNextPage, hasNextPage }
}
```

**usersAPI.ts**

```
export const getAllUsers = async () => {
   const {data} = await axios.get('/v1/users');
   return data;
}
```

**displayUsers.test.tsx**

```
describe('test display list users', () => {
      it("should handle failed get list users", () => {
        (useFetchListUsers as any).mockRejectedValueOnce({
            users: undefined,
        });
    
            render(
                <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
                    <ListUSers />
                </QueryClientProvider>,
                { store }
            );
            expect(await screen.findByTestId("noUsersAlert")).toBeTruthy();
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

if you mock the whole `useFetchListUsers` function, you cannot expect the `onError` callback defined inside of that function to be called, because you have mocked said function :)

Further, the `onError` callback is a callback to execute side-effects; things returned from that function have no meaning. In fact, the signature of `onError` is: `(err: TError) => void`, so it doesn't return anything.

I always advice to stub out the network layer with things like [mock-service-worker](https://mswjs.io/) instead of mocking complete hooks. This will ensure your tests are as close as possible to the real application.

If your `queryFn` returns a rejected Promise, the `error` property should be filled with that Error. If your UI reads the `error` property, you don't need `onError` at all - as I said, it's only for side effects.

In that case, making your mock so that it actually returns an error next to `users: undefined` might also do the trick.